# Editing the script of a js on a live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

```
//lots of html here
<script>
    var a = $('#a').val();
    $.post(url,{
        a: a
    });
</script>
```

suppose there is a webpage, `file.php`, like this and i wanna edit this page live. so if i use chrome dev tools then the edited script does not works. What i did was changed it a bit to...

```
$.post(url,{
    a :'edit'
});
```

Now this edited js does not works ! It still uses its prev code!

Comment: try clearing the browswer cache.

Comment: _It still uses its prev code!_...so what you can do is hit `f12` go to `Network` tab and in the network area you can right click and choose `clear browswer cache` and `clear broswer cookies`. Do this and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a browser caching issue. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, it will force your browser to refresh its static content.

Also if you refer to your JavaScript files with a unique query string, it will stop the browser from caching it.

*Please note that this may cause the load time of the site to increase as the browser won't be loading the JS file from its cache.*